# Calling a Method Java

Tags: java

I want to call this method:

```
 public int ArraySum(int[] a)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int Element;
        for(Element = 0; Element < a.length; Element++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[Element];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

in this method (which is in a different class):

```
public int Mean()
    {
        return (something.ArraySum(a))/2;
    }
```

I know that I probably need to create an object but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Because the method isn't static, you'll need an instance of the enclosing class. You haven't posted that. Also, Java method names should start with lower cases letter.

Comment: You might want to use `/a.length` instead of `/2`.

Comment: Elliott Frisch, could you please elaborate? I'm not sure hat you mean when you say enclosing class or that I'll need an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example:

```
public class C1
{
    //all the fields and stuff
    public int hello(int a)
{
     //all the code
}
    public static int hey(int a)
    {
     //all code
}
}
```

Note: One of the functions is static. Observe how we call them.

```
public class C2
{
 //all fields and stuff
 public void callerFunction()
{
    C1 obj=new C1();
     //created an object of class C1
    obj.hello(5);
    C1.hey(10);
     //only class name is required while calling static methods.
}
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that objects are required to call methods?

Comment: If the method is not static then you require an object to call it. Because every object has a separate copy of the method while static methods are class methods and are unique for all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the class `ArraySum` method is present in. E.g. if it's present in `Calculator` class like below:

```
public class Calculator{
  public int ArraySum(int[] a){
        int sum = 0;
        int Element;
        for(Element = 0; Element < a.length; Element++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[Element];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Then, what you need to do is (assuming that class doesn't define any non zero argument constructor),

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.ArraySum(..);
```